# Ping distroless Docker image doesn't work

Tags: docker, distroless

I've created the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as install

RUN apt update && \
    apt -y install iputils-ping

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11

COPY --from=install /usr/bin/ping ./ping
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2
COPY --from=install /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
COPY --from=install /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0

ENTRYPOINT ["./ping"]
```

But I don't understand why it doesn't work. I think that maybe the container stops before the process finishes.

```sh
$ docker run --rm distroless-ping 127.0.0.1
$ # no output from the run
```

At least, if I run it with no arguments I get the output:

```sh
$ docker run --rm distroless-ping
./ping: usage error: Destination address required
```

What's the issue here? I've tried using Docker's `CMD` instead of `ENTRYPOINT` but I got the same problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but the two `run` commands you show are the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what `gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11` is, exactly, but it looks as if it includes an incompatible runtime loader. If we copy the dynamic loader from the Ubuntu image...

```
COPY --from=install /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

...then it seems to work as expected:

```
$ docker run -it --rm pingtest 127.0.0.1
PING 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.104 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.020 ms
^C
--- 127.0.0.1 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.020/0.062/0.104/0.042 ms
```

---

This makes the final `Dockerfile` look like:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as install

RUN apt update && \
    apt -y install iputils-ping

FROM gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11

COPY --from=install /usr/bin/ping ./ping
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2
COPY --from=install /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
COPY --from=install /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0
COPY --from=install /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

ENTRYPOINT ["./ping"]
```

---

Note that with one additional library you can build the final image from `scratch` instead of `gcr.io/distroless/base-debian11`:

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04 as install

RUN apt update && \
    apt -y install iputils-ping

FROM scratch

COPY --from=install /usr/bin/ping ./ping
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libidn2.so.0
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libunistring.so.2
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0
COPY --from=install /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2
COPY --from=install /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

ENTRYPOINT ["./ping"]
```